# How to call server side code on textbox key enter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How do I call server side code for textbox's in asp.net when user presses enter key? Code behnid method is creating a dynamic control based upon a LINQ query from data table.

Comment: depending on what you exactly want to do, the answer ranges from "process the event in the code behind" to "set up an ajax handler" - please further specify what you're doing and what you've already tried

Comment: Use jQuery $.ajax or $.post that request webmethod on enter key.

Comment: Have you considered the lag/latency you would introduce trying to do this? What exactly are you trying to do? There is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: @Nicolas78 I am using LINQ to query data tables and/or sql queries from a database. Another dynamic control is created based upon the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbox has a [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event that will fire when the focus leaves the textbox.  If this isn't good enough for you, your going to need to use javascript and the onkeypress event.
As there's no description of what your doing after the event, I'm not sure what to offer as sample code.

Comment: Code behnid method is creating a dynamic control based upon a LINQ query from data table.

Comment: so would the textchanged event work for you?  IMO it's a good option here because if the user leaves the textbox you'll have a postback event where you can create your control.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion OP want to submit data with pressing enter in the `textbox`, then do sth with `string` from `textbox`.
So if I understand it right here is solution to do this:

```
//aspx
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmit" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID = "txbText"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</asp:Panel>



//aspx.cs
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string textFromTextBox = txbText.Text;
//do sth with that string
}
```